Conventions for "zero probability" implying "impossible"
Vol. 1, section I.7 of Feller's Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications (3rd ed.) states the following:

Given a discrete sample space $\mathfrak{S}$ with sample points $E_1, E_2, \ldots,$ we shall assume that with each point $E_{i}$...the probability of $E_{i}$ and denoted by $\mathbf{P}(E_{i})$. Note that we do not exclude the possibility that a point has probability zero...In discrete sample spaces probability zero is in practice interpreted as an impossibility, and any sample point known to have probability zero can, with impunity, be eliminated from the sample space.

Of course, for discrete random variables, it's not in general true that "zero probability" means "impossible":

Consider a probability space where the sample space $\Omega$ is the real numbers, with normal (zero-mean) probability distribution. Define the random variable $X(\omega)$ as: $-1$ if $\omega < 0$, $0$ if $\omega = 0$, and $1$ if $\omega > 0$. Then $X$ has three possible values $\{-1, 0, 1\}$, and $\mathbf{P}(X=0) = 0$, but clearly $X=0$ is not impossible.

But what Feller seems to be describing is a convention (for the case of a countable set of possible outcomes) whereby, unless stated otherwise, a probability of zero means "impossible" (i.e. "not actually a member of the set of possible outcomes").
This leaves me wondering: Is there a similar "convention" (commonly understood) for the uncountable case? (for simplicity, let's say the case of probability densities on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$)

Feller seems to maybe(?) imply something like this in vol. 2, for probability densities on $\mathbb{R}$: The language suggests (without quite explicitly saying it) that if the density is positive on the interval $[a, b]$ and zero elswehere, the default interpretation should be that the set of possible outcomes is only $[a, b]$
One could imagine generalizing this to densities on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ with a "convention" such as: if the density is uniformly zero in some neighborhood of a point $p$, then $p$ should (unless stated otherwise) be considered "impossible". But this is just a guess on my part.


The simple and most exact answer is that $\Omega$ denotes the set of  possible outcomes of a random experiment. So for a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb R$, we can consider any $X(\omega)$ as possible, regardless of probability.
This contradicts our intuition of associating probabilities with value $0$ as describing impossible events and events with probability $1$ as being certain.
The correct wording in mathematics to describe events $B$ such that
$$ P(B) = 1$$
is to say that $B$ is "almost sure" (and conversely we would say that $B^c$ is almost sure for $P(B) = 0.$)

However, if you want to think intuitively about this issue then yes, in practice, one would consider it "impossible" or arbitrarily unlikely to observe points whose density is 0 on a neighborhood of $x$.
The intuition of a density is that $f^X(x)$ itself approximates the probability of $X$ taking values near $x$.
One way that densities are commonly introduced is as derivatives of $$ x \to F^X(x) = P(X \leq x) = P^X( (-\infty,x])$$
so if you look at a small interval $\Delta x $ (note that $\Delta x$ is a set here and not a length) around $x$ then you have
$$ f^X(x) \approx \frac{P^X (\Delta x)}{ \\ length(\Delta x)}$$
which incidentally is where the formula
$$ P^X(B) = \int_B f^X(x) dx$$
comes from.
So when density is $0$ at $x$ the intuition is that there is a probability $0$ of being in a small neighborhood of $x$.

This is all useful information, but my question is about something different. My question is about when/whether a zero probability (or density) should be interpreted as meaning “impossible”. Feller articulates a convention for such an interpretation in the case of discrete state spaces. My question is whether any such convention exists for densities over $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

That's what I tried to answer. The answer is no. There is no such thing as "impossible" in probability because the starting point is to consider $\Omega$ as the set of all possible events.
As for intuition you are correct we would intuitively consider it "impossible" (prefer the term arbitrarily unlikely) to observe $x$ if $f^X(x) = 0$.
However this is only partially correct the proper statement would probably be (I'm not an expert on this topic) that an event $B \subset R$ is "impossible" if  $f^X(x) = 0$ for all $x \in B$  and $B$ is a set of non-zero measure.

The words "in practice" and "interpreted" are a signal that "impossible" is not being used in a strict sense in this case.
The actual conclusion that is to be reached is that, "In discrete sample spaces [...] any sample point known to have probability zero can, with impunity, be eliminated from the sample space."
This conclusion is not true if we omit the word "discrete." Your example is an example of an uncountable sample space, and we cannot just eliminate zero-probability outcomes "with impunity."
What Feller is referring to by eliminating zero-probability outcomes is the way we handle actual discrete sample spaces in many cases; for example, the outcomes of tossing a fair coin are $\{H,T\}$ and not $\{H, T, E\}$ where $E$ represents the coin coming to rest on an edge. We could use $\{H, T, E\}$ as our sample space and assign $P(H)=P(T)=\frac12$ and $P(E)=0,$ but in practice we usually don't even list $E$ as an outcome.
A crucial difference between the sample space $\{H,T\}$ and your example is that when I say the sample space is $\{H,T\},$ I mean that's all there is; I'm not constructing a set of events $\{H,T\}$ on top of some other sample space.

Note that Feller is not saying that an event with zero probability must be considered "impossible", even in a discrete sample space.
When he writes, "we do not exclude the possibility that a point [in a discrete sample space] has probability zero", he means exactly what he wrote:
you may have zero-probability events in a discrete sample space,
and you are not required to eliminate them.
The notions "possible" and "impossible" are not formally defined in probability theory. There is only the membership of the sample space and the probability of events. Feller is giving you permission to attach the word "impossible" to some zero-probability events in certain circumstances.
Let's consider these examples from the question:

if the density is positive on the interval $[a, b]$ and zero elsewhere, the default interpretation should be that the set of possible outcomes is only $[a, b]$

That is certainly a permissible interpretation. Depending on what you are modeling, you may find it a useful interpretation.

if the density is uniformly zero in some neighborhood of a point $p$ [in $\mathbb R^n$], then $p$ should (unless stated otherwise) be considered "impossible".

Again, that is a permissible interpretation. You may find that it is a desirable interpretation of whatever phenomenon you are modeling with a particular sample space.
On the other hand, if such an interpretation leads to conclusions that are objectionable to you for some reason, choose a different interpretation.
I do not believe one can give a blanket recommendation that will cover all possible real-world applications.
So yes, there is a meaningful distinction between "impossible" and "zero probability", but this distinction is outside the domain of probability theory. It is a distinction that you must decide how to make depending on what the word "impossible" means to you in the context of a given application of probability.
For example, suppose you are looking at the distribution of scores on a test whose questions have a total value of $100$ points. Is it "possible" that after answering every question correctly (earning full marks), a student starts idly scribbling on the exam paper and writes a succinct proof of the Collatz conjecture, and that the grader then decides this is worth five points extra credit, so that the student ends up with a score of $105$? Certainly if you are working with old-fashioned pen-and-paper tests it is physically possible for a grader to write a number greater than $100$ on an exam paper even though there are only $100$ points of questions on the exam.
But you might decide to assign such scores zero probability anyway,
or even exclude them from your sample space, when you model the scoring of the test as a probability space.
Feller also (implicitly) gives you permission not to exclude every zero-probability point from every discrete sample space.
So you may, if you like, construct a discrete sample space from a subset of the integers, and assign zero probability to some of the integers in your sample space. For example, for a fair six-sided die, you could say the sample space is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ but $P(0)=0$. I don't recall every seeing someone do this, but it's permitted.

It seems like there’s a meaningful distinction between zero probability and “impossible”. If an experiment is counting alpha decay particles, then negative values are truly “impossible”, not merely “zero probability”. If the random variable has to do with test scores graded on a scale of 0-100, then values > 100 are similarly “impossible”

Thanks for the additional info. BTW, since you mentioned the lack of a formal definition of “impossible”, just wanted to re-clarify: If my sample space is the outcome of some inherently integer-valued experiment (e.g. particle counts) and I say (for some positive integer $x_{0}$) that $\mathbf{P}(x_{0}) = 0$ implies $x_{0}$ is “impossible”, I’m using “impossible” as shorthand for “$x_{0}$ actually isn’t a member of the sample space at all”. It sounds like you are using “impossible” with the same meaning, correct?

You can't even write $P(x_0)$ unless $x_0$ represents an event in your probability space, so in your example, I think $x_0$ has to be in the sample space. As for the word "impossible," I'm trying very hard to avoid adopting any definition at all for myself in this answer. I merely mention some ways in which you might use the word.

Well, the sense in which I’m using the word “impossible” is based on what I understand Feller to be saying. Also these lecture notes (e.g. 5th page) use the word “impossible” as if it had a clear meaning (a meaning distinct from just “zero probability”). In any case, hopefully it’s been clear from the outset the meaning that I’ve been attaching to the word “impossible”? (I tried to be explicit about it in the paragraph following the first bullet point in the question)

I understand Feller to be saying something different than you think. The phrase "eliminated from the sample space" is an important clue. It implies that we have not even yet settled on a choice of sample space and probability function for whatever problem it is that we are working on. And if we haven't even decided what the domain of our probability function is, what does "probability zero" even mean? I think the interpretation you're trying to make is essentially unworkable.

So to summarize, it sounds like your understanding of what Feller’s saying is: 1) We haven’t fully settled on a choice of sample space, and the values of $x$ for which $\mathbf{P}(x) = 0$ are the values which we could potentially eliminate from the sample space (depending on how we think about the underlying phenomenon being modeled by our probability space). 2) However there’s no established “default” convention about which values should be eliminated from the sample space. Correct?

That sounds about right.

Thanks. One thing that’s still not abundantly clear to me is the status of the term “impossible”. In addition to the lecture notes I linked to previously, the notes here and here (esp. pg. 33) speak of “impossible” events and sample points as if the term “impossible” had a well-understood meaning (a meaning different than just “zero probability”). But I guess that’s a topic for a separate question.

With regard to this question, thanks for your detailed answer and follow-up comments.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ denote the probability space. Maybe Feller wants to say, that in terms of your probability measure $P$ it does not matter, if you look at the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ or $\mathcal{F}\backslash \mathcal{N}$, where $\mathcal{N}\subsetneq \mathcal{N}_P=\{A\in\mathcal{F}:P(A)=0\}$. (Of course you need to keep $\emptyset$ in a $\sigma$-algebra.)
But note, that he says that "you can [...] eliminate sample states with probability zero". From my experience, this is not a convention, since you come across all sorts of zero sets in probability theory.
For $\mathcal{U}([a,b])$, you could say, that you do not have the state space $\mathbb{R}$ with density function $\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}$, but the state space $(a,b)$ with density function $\mathbb{1}_{(a,b)\backslash\mathbb{Q}}$. This is certainly unpractical and gives reason why you would want to allow sets with measure zero in your $\sigma$-algebra.
Another example would be an infinite fair coin flip on $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. The first thing you might think of is just one specific infinite coin flip $\omega=(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots)\in\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ even though $P(\omega)=0$. On the other hand, for instance, predicting the first $n$ flips has probability
$$P(\{\omega_1\}\times\ldots\times\{\omega_n\}\times\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N})=\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Just to be extra clear about what I understand Feller to be saying: Suppose I'm told there's a discrete probability space intended to model some inherently non-negative integer-valued phenomenon (particle count registered by a detector, or something like that), and I'm told that the probability of observing a count of $n$ is of the form, say, $C \cdot \mathrm{max}{(2^{-(n+1)} - 2^{-k}), 0}$ for positive constants $C$ and $k$ (this distribution is positive for $0 \leq n < k-1$ and zero for $n \geq k-1$), but it's not explicitly stated what the sample space is supposed to be...(1/2)

...In such a scenario, the fact that $\mathbf{P}(n) = 0$ for $n \geq k-1$ (and the lack of any explicit specification about the intended sample space) means that according to Feller's alleged convention on how it's to be "interpreted in practice", we should make the additional inference that integers $n \geq k-1$ are intended to not even be members of the sample space at all. But it sounds like you don't agree that this actually is a generally agreed-upon "convention". Am I reading you correctly here? (2/2)

Feller says "we do not exclude the possibility that a point has probability zero". And later on he is saying, that you can delete those samples, if you wish. You can use both sample spaces without noticing a difference when doing computations with your probability measure $P$. But, since he is not excluding the events of probability zero, "his convention" is the allowance of events with zero probability in the sample space.
